# display images from iOS gallery

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, nsurl, xamarin.forms

Through a platform-dependent service I've managed to fetch the NSUrl of an image from one of the galleries on the device. It looks like this: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=01202427-4916-4F8F-99AA-D38D88181558&ext=JPG".
How can I  use it to set the source of an Image view in the Xamarin.Forms shared project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using a stream:

```
var s = originalImage.AsPNG ().AsStream ();
SharedView.SetImageStream(s);
```

In the PCL side:

```
public void SetImageStream(System.IO.Stream s)
{
    theImageView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => s);
}
```